# Add form confirmation based on php database result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form which is populated by a database, currently I have a jQuery script added in order to make sure that at least one checkbox has been selected and is working as desired. I am now needing to add a second element to the submit functionality and that is a confirmation popup, however I only need the popup to appear if the user has a value of X in his table row within a specific column.

Initially I thought it would be as easy as a onsubmit php if statement so I added this to my form tag.

```
 <form action="" method="post" <?php if($value1 == $value2){echo 'onsubmit="return confirm($confirmtext)"';}?> id="form">
```

where:

$value1 is the value in the database and I can verify is populating X as a value

value2 is the value to match which is also X

$confirmtext is the text that I want to ahve produced

all three php variables are populating successfully and the onsubmit element does in fact appear as

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm($oowsubmit)" id="selection-form">
```

however I am not seeing a confirm box appear prior to the form submitting.

I also have a jQuery validation as displayed below

```
 <script>
 //dom ready handler
 jQuery(function ($) {
     //form submit handler
     $('#form').submit(function (e) {
         //check atleat 1 checkbox is checked
         if (!$('.pick').is(':checked')) {
             //prevent the default form submit if it is not checked
             e.preventDefault();

        alert('Before proceeding, you must select at least one box');
         }

     })
 })
 </script>
```

Is the jQuery validation getting in the way?

Is there a reason my onsubmit is not producing if not?

What would be the best way to handle adding this type of confirmation box?

any sample snippets are always appreciated and I thank all in advance for their insight on this.

Comment: <form action="" method="post" <?php
  if($value1 == $value2) {
   ?>onsubmit="return confirm('<?php echo  $confirmtext; ?>');" <?php
  }
?> id="form">

Comment: John, you are a legend mate. I had to push the last \' over a spot and dropped in the text in replace of $confirmtext but is working like a charm, thanks mate. I will update my answer and mark it closed.

Answer (score 0):

With John V's advice I was able to get the form working as I desired with the initial onsubmit solution I had implemented. It is little things like this as to why it is sometimes so important to have a second set of eyes.

I initially had:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm($oowsubmit)" id="selection-form">
```

notice the

```
 confirm($oowsubmit)
```

The $oowsubmit variable is not being contained within single quotes as it should be and as a result is not correctly populating.

The updated code is as follows:

```
 <form action="" method="post" <?php if($value1 == $value2){echo 'onsubmit="return confirm(\'my confirmation message.\')"';}?> id="form">
```

the form is now initially processing the confirmation only if the onsubmit appears based on the value1/value2 comparison. The jQuery validation is also still working.

Thanks to the stack exchange community